# エラーの原因がわかりません

Tags: c

C言語です。名前、点数が約300名分記載されたファイルを読み込み、偏差値を加えて表示するといったプログラムです。
以下のコードによりファイルを読み込むと、その下にあるエラー？が表示されます。

解決方法を教えてください。質問内容が不十分でしたらその旨も教えてください。

これまでに試したこととして、「syntax error near unexpected token `('」がカッコの種類が違うみたいな記事を見つけたのですが、どこが違うのかがわかりませんでした。

```
#include <stdio.h>   /*ヘッダファイル。標準入出力ライブラリ*/
#include <string.h>  /*文字列処理に関するライブラリ*/
#include <math.h>  /*数学関数に関するライブラリ*/
#define DATA_MAX 400 /* 扱える最大人数 */
#define STRING_LENGTH 41 /* 文字列の最大字数 (日本語なら 2 倍) + 1*/

typedef struct personal_data { /* 構造体の定義 */
  char name[STRING_LENGTH];    /* 氏名 (日本語STRING_LENGTH-1文字) */
  double score;                /* 点数 */
} personal_data;               /*構造体の名称定義*/
void print_data(personal_data x[], int num, double sum); /*関数宣言*/

int main() {                    /*main関数*/
  personal_data data[DATA_MAX]; /*文字列を構造体を入れる*/
  int num = 0 /* 読み込んだ人数 */, read_result /* データの読み込み結果 */;
  char tmpChar[STRING_LENGTH] /* 氏名の一時的な読み込み先 */,
      read_format[20] = "%100s" /* 文字列の読み込みフォーマット */;
  double sum = 0; /*点数合計を保存用の変数*/

  sprintf(read_format, "%%%ds",
          STRING_LENGTH - 1); /* 読み込む文字列の書式生成 */
  printf("名前と点数を入力(終了は[Ctrl]+[Z]/[D]\n"); /*入力促進*/
  while (1) { /*読み込みの繰り返し処理*/
    read_result = scanf(
        read_format, tmpChar); /*1回目の読み込み結果を読み込みフォーマットに*/
    if (read_result == EOF) {     /*ファイルの中身なし*/
      break;                      /*ループ脱却*/
    } else if (num >= DATA_MAX) { /*データ数が最大値かどうか確認*/
      printf("扱える文字数は%dまで\n",
             DATA_MAX); /*最大値を超える場合その旨を出力*/
      return 1;         /*異常終了*/
    }
    strcpy(data[num].name, tmpChar); /* 一時的な読み込み先からデータコピー*/
    read_result = scanf("%lg", &data[num].score); /*読み込み*/
    if (read_result == EOF) { /*ファイル終着点の処理*/
      break;                  /*ループ脱却*/
    }                         /* 名前、点数読み込み成功 */
    sum += data[num].score; /*点数合計計算*/
    num++;                  /* 読み込んだ人数カウント・アップ */
    
  }
  print_data(data, num, sum); /*関数に数値を渡す*/
  return 0;                   /*正常終了*/
}

void print_data(personal_data x[], int num, double sum) {
                 /* 関数に配列データを渡す */
  int i,j;                      /*配列データを特定するための変数*/
  double ave = 0,h = 0, sigma = 0;                /*平均 標準偏差*/
  ave = sum / num;   /*平均の計算*/
  for( j = 0, sigma = 0.0; j < num; ++j ){   /*分散の計算*/
 sigma += pow( x[j].score - ave, 2.0 );  /*分散の式*/
 }
 
/*sigma = sqrt( sigma / ( j - 1 ) );   標準偏差の計算結果*/
 for (i = 0; i < num; i++) { /*人数分を一行ずつ表示*/
   /*偏差値計算*/
  h = x[i].score - ave;
    printf("%s\t%g\t%g\n", x[i].name, x[i].score,h/sigma * 10 + 50); /*名前、点数、偏差値*/
 }
  return; /*戻り値なし*/
}
```

```
./ファイル名: line 7: typedef: command not found
./ファイル名: line 8: syntax error near unexpected token `('
./ファイル名: line 8: `  char name[STRING_LENGTH];    /* 氏名 (日本語STRING_LENGTH-1文字) */'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

そのCコードのファイル名は `./ファイル名` で、あなたはおそらくシェル上で

```
sh ./ファイル名
```

のようにするかどうかして、そのコードを**シェルスクリプト**として実行したのでしょう。

Cプログラムはコンパイルして**実行可能ファイル**を生成させることが必要です。
そのコードを、たとえば `test.c` というファイルにして、

```
cc test.c -o test
```

または

```
make test
```

を実行して `./test` という実行可能ファイルを生成させ、シェルで

```
./test
```

を実行します。

Comment: とてもわかりやすい説明ありがとうございます！ファイルを読み込むことができました！偏差値の計算が上手くいかないですが、この質問は解決とさせていただきます！